# How to change the Node.js module wrapper?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules

For testing purposes I need to change the Node.js `Module` wrapper.

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname, process, global) {  
    debugger;
 });
```

Played around with `Module` I found

```
var Module = require("module")
Module.wrapper
-> ["(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname, process, global) { ", "
});"]

Module.wrap
-> function(script) {
    return NativeModule.wrapper[0] + script + NativeModule.wrapper[1];
}
```

Is it possible to hook into `Module.wraper` or property to change the script wrapping?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You've done a great job by finding the `Module.wrap` function. How about simply overwriting it?

Imagine that you have two files, `main.js` and `module.js`. In `main.js` you overwrite the `Module.wrap` function in order to `console.log('debug');` every time a module is required. Then you require `module.js`, which contains a hello world message.

`main.js`:

```js
var Module = require("module");

(function(moduleWrapCopy) {
  Module.wrap = function(script) {
    script = "console.log('debug');" + script
    return moduleWrapCopy(script); // Call original wrapper function
  };
}(Module.wrap)); // Pass original function to IIFE

require("./module.js");
```

`module.js`:

```js
console.log("Hello world from module.js!");
```

Executing `node main.js` results in:

> ```
> debug
> Hello world from module.js!
> ```

---

This also works with nested `require()` calls, for example if you `require("./module2.js")` in `module.js`:

`module.js`:

```js
console.log("Hello world from module.js!");

require("./module2.js");
```

`module2.js`:

```js
console.log("Hello world from module2.js!");
```

In this case `node main.js` produces:

> ```
> debug
> Hello world from module.js!
> debug
> Hello world from module2.js!
> ```

Tested on Node.js 4.3.0 and 6.1.0.

Answer (score 3):

You can override, the `require` by your own method. For example

```
require = function(module_name) {
  var js = openTheModuleIndexFile(module_name)
  var wrapped = wrapTheModule(js)
  eval(wrapped)
}
```

All you have to do is to implement the `openTheModuleIndexFile` function, and `wrapTheModule` which your wrapping function.

(Don't forget the `module_name` can be exists is `node_modules` of this directory, parent directory, or child directery, it's even can be just a JS file name)

I'm sure, you need to make same hacks, but in the end, it should work.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately eval is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the wrapper inside node app, without override the require function. **but** you can fork (copy) node source to your computer, change one line & compile (build) it.

This why he love open-source :)

All you have to do is change one line of code if *src/node.js* file

here:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/node.js#L990

```
NativeModule.wrapper = [
    '(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { ',
    '\n});'
  ];
```